# Javascript on editor template

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page to add outcomes to a areas on a form. I utilise Editor templates to group the outcomes into areas and allow the outcome to be selected from a drop down list. I'd like to show an optional comments box for two of the 3 possible outcomes.

The main page is the following:

```
@model DBS.ViewModels.OutcomeQuestionnaireVM

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Outcomes";
}

<h2>Add Outcomes</h2>
@if (Model.Error == true)
{
<h3 class="danger">You MUST select an outcome for at least 1 area.</h3>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DebriefId)

    <hr />

    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Groups, new { outcomes = Model.Outcomes })


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Next" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

The group editor template is:

```
@model DBS.ViewModels.OutcomeQuestionGroupVM
@{
Layout = null;
} 

<h4>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)</h4>


@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Questions, new { outcomes = ViewData["outcomes"] })
```

The final editor template for the outcome is:

```
@model DBS.ViewModels.OutcomeQuestionVM
@{
Layout = null;
}

<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Question)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OutcomeId,  (SelectList)ViewData["outcomes"], "Please Select if applicable", new { @class =  "form-control", @id = "OutcomeId" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OutcomeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="Comments">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Comments)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => Model.Comments, htmlAttributes: new {   @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Comments, "", new { @class = "text-  danger" })
    </div>
</div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        document.getElementById('Comments').hide;
    });

    $(function () {
        $(".DropChange").change(function () {
            var valone = $('#OutcomeId').val();

            if (valone == 1 || valone == 2)
            {
                $('#Comments').show();
            }
            else if (valone == 3)
            {
                $('#Comments').hide();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#Comments').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

However javascript doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sections are not supported in partial views, which is fortunate in your case or you would be adding multiple inline copies of each script in the `jqueryval` bundle as well as your own script (one each time the template is added).

Your also generating invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes generated by `new { id = "OutcomeId" }` and `<div class="col-md-4" id="Comments">` which means the script would never have worked anyway.

You are also generating a hidden input for `Comments` before the textarea for the same property, which means that when the form is submitted, the value of `Comments` will be the initial value (as generated by `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Comments)`) and the value of the `<textarea>` would be ignored.

Its the responsibility of the view to include the scripts, not the partial, so move the scripts to the main view (or layout) and use class names and relative selectors.

Your html in the template should be

```cs
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Question)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
        // add class name to handle the .change() event
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OutcomeId,  (SelectList)ViewData["outcomes"], "Please Select if applicable", new { @class =  "form-control outcome" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OutcomeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" class="comments"> // use class name
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => Model.Comments, htmlAttributes: new {   @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Comments, "", new { @class = "text-  danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

then include css to initially hide all comments

```
.comments {
    display: none;
}
```

and the script in the main view

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".outcome").change(function () {
            var valone = $(this).val();
            // get the associated comment
            var comment = $(this).closest('.row').find('.comments');
            if (valone == 1 || valone == 2) {
                comment.show();
            } else {
                comment.hide();
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

Note it was not clear what `$(".DropChange")` was referring to but I assume its the dropdownlist in your template (which I gave `class="outcome"`)